Ошибка в файле TypeScript VSCODE
Я пишу плагин для сервера в майнкрафт, начинаю инициализировать проект, создаю main.ts, импортирую библиотеки и вижу это

В node_modules закинул, в package.json прописал, помогите пожалуйста

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

как вы устанавливали зависимость? просто кинули в папку и прописали в package.json?

@MoloF, да, так и сделал

npm install --save @customrealms/core правильная устанавка библиотеки есть в документации https://customrealms.io/core/. для верности, после установки можно перезапустить ide
